# Recuperar el índice de un dropsown

Tags: javascript, html, angular

En el ejemplo que pongo a continucación recupero el valor que se ha seleccionado en el DropDown pero me gustaría poder recuperar el índice.

```
<select #sectionIncident (change)=cambioSeccion(sectionIncident.value)>
   <option *ngFor="let seccion of secciones " [value]="seccion " >{{seccion}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

*ngFor tiene un parámetro index al que puedes acceder de la siguiente forma

```
<select #sectionIncident (change)=cambioSeccion(sectionIncident.value)>
   <option *ngFor="let seccion of secciones; let i = index" [value]="seccion" >
      {{seccion}} || El índice de la iteración es: {{ i }}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!!

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución haciendo pruebas.

```
<select #centroIncident (change)=cambioCentro(centroIncident.value)">
     <option *ngFor="let centro of centrosComboBox; let i = index " [value]="i" [selected]="i==0" >{{centro}}</option>
</select>
```

He utilizado un indice para que siempre se seleccione la primera opción al cargarse la página y ese indice lo mando con la etiqueta Value.